# Apart from conditional formatting, is there a way to filter by values in this example to find out the top companies that meet all the criteria?

Tags: excel, formatting, visualization

I have a group of companies in this table, ranked based on 1 to 4, 1 being the lowest and 4 being the highest, on 4 different criteria. I intend to find the top companies that meet either 1, 2, 3 or all 4 criteria. Apart from conditional formatting, I am unsure on the best method to help filter the data to find the top companies. In addition, I am also unsure (apart from manually counting) to help visualize the data based on the number of companies that meet the criteria.

I hope that the above explanation is clear enough and am glad to provide any other info if needed.

Intended outcome: I hope to be able to visualise the top companies with at least 1 criteria met, 2 criteria met, 3 criteria met and all 4 criteria met in a table. I am not sure whether this is possible and am open to suggestions on how it may be done.

[Google sheet link to the table below](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WLBKKjoy_4tdmlB5TkjhvmQZDCCgDiHyLIgzFFd4_kw)

[image]

Comment: Add the 4 results, highest is best.

Comment: I would like to visualise them individually as well. Is there another way? :)

Comment: Can you please show us what the expected outcome is?

Comment: And its best to paste a textual data instead of image, so someone trying to provide a solution, can easily copy the same from here, and provide otherwise needs to type all of it manually, obviously with the expected output as well as mentioned by @cybernetic.nomad

Comment: I have included what I think the intended outcome would be, as well as a link to the data. Hope this helps! :) @cybernetic.nomad

Comment: I have included what I think the intended outcome would be, as well as a link to the data. Hope this helps! :) @MayukhBhattacharya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need use a `FILTER()` Function to arrive at the expected outcome,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `H2`

```
=FILTER(B2:F19,(C2:C19>2.2)*(D2:D19>2.5)*(E2:E19>3.3)*(F2:F19>2.1))
```

> OP asked, whether it is possible to show all the criteria, individually as well, then the same formula works for us as well,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `H2`

```
=FILTER(B2:C19,C2:C19>2.2)
```

• Formula used in cell `K2`

```
=FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},B2:B19,D2:D19),D2:D19>2.5)
```

Or,

```
=FILTER(FILTER(B2:F19,D2:D19>2.5),{1,0,1,0,0})
```

• Formula used in cell `N2`

```
=FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},B2:B19,E2:E19),E2:E19>3.3)
```

Or,

```
=FILTER(FILTER(B2:F19,E2:E19>3.3),{1,0,0,1,0})
```